# How can i implement super() with multiple init inheritances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

I was doing an exercise that involved multiple inheritances with initializers that had multiple amount of arguments required and thought, how could super() solve this instead of manually call each superclass?

```py
class One:
    def __init__(self, address, phone):
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone

class Two:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city

class Three(One,Two):
    def __init__(self, country, address, phone, city):
        self.country = country
        One.__init__(self, address, phone)
        Two.__init__(self, city)
        print(f"{address}, " + f"{phone}, " + f"{self.city}, " + f"{self.country}")

i = Three("Acountry", "AnAddress", "Aphone", "Acity")
```

This works fine, all the arguments are printed well and in order, but i don't know how to implement `super()` here.

I tried adding 2 supers on the subclass:

```py
        super().__init__(address, phone)
        super().__init__(city)
```

And even add a super() on the parent class to make it point to `class Two`:

```py
class One:
    def __init__(self, address, phone, city):
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        super().__init__(city)

class Two:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city

class Three(One,Two):
    def __init__(self, country, address, phone, city):
        self.country = country
        super().__init__(address, phone)
        print(f"{address}, " + f"{phone}, " + f"{self.city}, " + f"{self.country}")

i = Three("Acountry", "AnAddress", "Aphone", "Acity")
```

It doesn't work.

How can i implement `super()` in the original code that works?

Comment: Refer [how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [this article by Raymond Hettinger](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super), which goes over how `super` is designed to work, and outlines how your classes using it should look.  He recommends passing arguments as keyword arguments and calling `super().__init__` at the end of every `__init__`:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, address, phone, **kwargs):
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Two:
    def __init__(self, city, **kwargs):
        self.city = city
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Three(One,Two):
    def __init__(self, country, address, phone, city, **kwargs):
        self.country = country
        super().__init__(address=address, phone=phone, city=city, **kwargs)
        print(f"{address}, " + f"{phone}, " + f"{self.city}, " + f"{self.country}")

i = Three("Acountry", "AnAddress", "Aphone", "Acity")
```

Comment: One suggestion: `Three.__init__` doesn't have to duplicate the `address`, `phone`, and `city` parameters if you use keyword arguments when instantiating `Three`. (And you can enforce the use of keyword arguments by making all three keyword-only parameters.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way to solve this without args and kwargs? Originally, this example was to make emphasis on how more complicated a inheritance is without args and kwargs. Also, which class would the super() on class Two call? The default object class?